# PHP/MongoDB - sort by time

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following MongoDB object:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("50954f0d13f88da4a590e5ff"),
   "uname": "Eamorr",
   "1": {
     "table": "1",
     "color": "red",
     "time": NumberInt(1351963491),
     "niceTime": "2012-11-03T17: 24: 51+00: 00"
  },
   "3": {
     "table": "3",
     "color": "green",
     "time": NumberInt(1351963567),
     "niceTime": "2012-11-03T17: 26: 07+00: 00"
  },
   "4": {
     "table": "4",
     "color": "orange",
     "time": NumberInt(1351963506),
     "niceTime": "2012-11-03T17: 25: 06+00: 00"
  }
}
```

How do I sort this object by 'time'?

I want `table 3` to be first, `table 4` to be second and `table 1` to be last in the list.

I'm really stuck... Please help!

---

Update:
I should add, that my server returns the following JSON object:

```
[{
    "table": "4",
    "color": "orange",
    "time": 1351965770,
    "niceTime": "2012-11-03T18:02:50+00:00"
}, {
    "table": "3",
    "color": "red",
    "time": 1351964379,
    "niceTime": "2012-11-03T17:39:39+00:00"
}, {
    "table": "1",
    "color": "red",
    "time": 1351964997,
    "niceTime": "2012-11-03T17:49:57+00:00"
}]
```

Is it easier to sort this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
$coll->find($range, $co)->sort(array('time' => -1) );
```

Comment: this will not sort embedded array inside object

Comment: ach, so redesign table: data = [] , then sort data.time

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

Using the second JSON (above), I did:

```
function my_sort($a, $b){
    if ($a['time'] > $b['time']) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($a['time'] < $b['time']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

usort($obj,'my_sort');
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: When sorting small data is OK, when grow try caching + PHP V8 http://we-love-php.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-v8-javascript-engine-as-php.html